# Particle effects in a uiview

Tags: uiview, quartz-graphics, effects, particle-system

I'd like to write/use particle effects in a uiview so I'm thinking of writing a simple one using quartz. It'd be strictly 2d. Am I shooting myself in the foot by not using gl, or are there othet projects or solutions out there that wrap particle systems nicely in a uiview?

Answer (score 0):

[Cocos2d for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) has some really neat particle effects. Maybe check there? It can run on the Mac too iirc.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 5, you can use the UIKit Particle System to achieve what you want. Here's a tutorial on that: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Cocos2d view on the top of all Views, then run cocos2d particle. Check my demo here: https://github.com/lephukhanhhuy/KHParticleView